# Custom Permission Not Appearing in /admin/people/permissions

Tags: 8

I have a custom module `my_module` for Drupal 8 and I've added a custom permission yml file with 1 static permission:

modules/my_module/my_module.permissions.yml

```
My Custom Feature Permission:
  title: 'Access custom feature'
  description: 'Gives access to the custom feature.'
  restrict access: true
```

modules/my_module/my_module.info.yml

```
name: 'My custom module'
type: module
description: 'Blah'
core: 8.x
package: 'My Company'
```

I was expecting to see a new permission show up in mysite.com/admin/people/permissions under the category "My Company" but there is none.

Is there something else I need to do to get the permission to show in `/admin/people/permissions`?

I've been following these instructions:

- https://benmarshall.me/drupal-8-module-permissions/
- https://www.aram.cz/article/custom-permissions-drupal-8

Comment: Well, if you accurately named the files you listed above, then you need to switch the contents of the files, then enable the module.

Comment: @jaypan, the filenames above were wrong; I have corrected this post to match the actual file names. Thanks

Comment: And have you cleared the registry, and/or enabled the module?

Comment: I have flushed all caches if thats what you mean? And enabled the module

Comment: I recreated your code exactly on a local Drupal site and the permission showed up for me. All I did was copy your code, enable the module & flush cache. So there must be another reason why it is not showing up for you. Maybe double check your files are named correctly? `[module_machine_name].permissions.yml` for example.

Comment: Oh, they are showing up. I was expecting to see the text "My Custom Feature" on the permission page, but that text is not shown. Instead, the "category" name on the permission page is the name of the route to which that permission has been set. Thanks all!

Comment: That can't be from the code you've shown. You must have something else screwy in your system, you may want to figure that out before you find out what it is the hard way.